# Compile gradle Error for support library v24

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, android-tablayout

I get the error message

> failed to resolve com.android.support.design:24.0.0

after I use new gradle (v.2.10).
I want use this library to support tablayout.

Before I update my gradle, compile '`com.android.support:design:23.1.0`' its ok.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Is it typo? Separete with ":" not ".".  Like this "com.android.support:design:24.0.0"

Comment: Thanks @stkent : It's work

Comment: Update your compileSdkVersion to version 24 and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first ,

- You should update your **SDK Manager**

Then set this in your `build.gradle` section .

```
 compileSdkVersion 24
 buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks @Intellij Amiya : It's Work

Comment: @AzdaFirmansyah if it worked for you then you could accept the answer